# How to set referer when user comes from Google Chrome app icon?

Tags: google-chrome, chromium, http-referer

I have a chrome app which basically is just a visual bookmark which sends the visitors to my website.

Currently it doesn't show any referer because technically the user came directly to the website.

Is there a way to detect this?

I understand I can append some query parameters in the URL of the chrome app but I am wondering if there's a cleaner solution than this.

Answer (score -1):

The chrome.webRequest property should allow you to set the information you need. I couldn't find exact details that would help but there is an Auth option which you may be able to use as a referrer.

Hope this helps. Sorry I could not help further.

https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/webRequest.html

Comment: I'd love to see the wally who hit down but couldn't provide any help whatsoever.